# Transmitting POST-event to Google Calendar using Perl and Net::OAuth2

Tags: perl, post, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm developing a webapp in Perl and try to create events in user's Google Calendar with OAuth2. Authentication and requesting calendar-data is working fine, I'm just totally stuck  when it comes to sending a POST-request and attaching JSON- or hash-data to it. Are there methods coming with the module for this? The documentation does not point me anywhere here.
I guess LWP would provide ways, but this seems like a lot of overhead.

Here is how i accomplished getting calendar-events so far (as a simple console-app for now):

```
use Net::OAuth2::Profile::WebServer;

my $auth = Net::OAuth2::Profile::WebServer->new
    ( name           => 'Google Calendar'
    , client_id      => $id
    , client_secret  => $secret
    , site           => 'https://accounts.google.com'
    , scope          => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
    , authorize_path    => '/o/oauth2/auth'
    , access_token_path => '/o/oauth2/token'
    , redirect_uri      => $redirect
    );

print $auth->authorize_response->as_string;
my $code=<STDIN>;

my $access_token = $auth->get_access_token($code);

my $response = $access_token->get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/2j6r4iegh2u8o2409jk8k2g838@group.calendar.google.com/events');
  $response->is_success
      or die "error: " . $response->status_line;

print $response->decoded_content;
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's time to answer my own question.
To transmit JSON in a POST-request (creating a calendar-event) I ended up using LWP::UserAgent and HTTP::Request. For setting the content-type I first had to create an HTTP::Request-object and set header and data:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendarID>/events' );
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( "{ 'summary': 'EventName', 'start': { 'dateTime': '2015-02-11T20:48:00+01:00' }, 'end': { 'dateTime': '2015-02-11T22:30:00+01:00' } }" );
```

Then I created an LWP::UserAgent-object, appended the OAuth2-token to it and let it fire the request:

```
my $apiUA = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$apiUA->default_header(Authorization => 'Bearer ' . $access_token->access_token() );

my $apiResponse = $apiUA->request( $req );
```

It's that simple. Would've been a lot nicer to do this all-in-one with Net::OAuth2, though.